# Can I disable the Chatter mention?

Tags: chatter, mentions, disable

I would ask if I can disable the Chatter mention in a standard way or I must use a custom solution as a Trigger.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Apex Triggers is the only option AFAIK to restrict mention on user/group level.

**Suggestion**: Use hierarchical custom setting to make the user/profile configurable.

There is [would be] a feature available for groups:

1. [Keep Discussions Focused with Broadcast Groups—Generally Available](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_groups_broadcast.htm?edition=&impact=)
2. [Broadcast Groups—Pilot](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_chatter_groups_broadcast.htm?edition=&impact=)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two triggers, on FeedItem and FeedComment.

FeedItem Trigger:

```
trigger MentionFeedItem on FeedItem (before insert, before update) {

List<User> listUserPlatform = [SELECT ID, Name FROM User];
List<String> listNameUserPlatform = new List<String>();

for(User u : listaUserPlatform) {
    listNameUserPlatform.add('@'+u.Name);
}

for(FeedItem f : Trigger.new) {
    Boolean nameFinded = false;
    for(Integer i=0; i < listNameUserPlatform.size() && !nameFinded; i++) {
        if( f.Body.contains(listNameUserPlatform.get(i)) ) {
            nameFinded=true;
            f.addError('You can\'t use mention');
        }
    }
}
```

FeedComment trigger:

```
trigger MentionFeedComment on FeedComment (before insert, before update) {

List<User> listUserPlatform = [SELECT ID, Name FROM User];
List<String> listNameUserPlatform = new List<String>();

for(User u : listaUserPlatform) {
    listNameUserPlatform.add('@'+u.Name);
}

for(FeedComment f : Trigger.new) {
    Boolean nameFinded = false;
    for(Integer i=0; i < listNameUserPlatform.size() && !nameFinded; i++) {
        if( f.CommentBody .contains(listNameUserPlatform.get(i)) ) {
            nameFinded=true;
            f.addError('You can\'t use mention');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To basically disable mentions in Salesforce Communities specifically:

1.) In Setup ---> Sharing Settings, Set the Default External Access "Users" to private.

2.) In Setup ---> Sharing Settings, Uncheck both "Portal User Visibility" and "Community User Visibility" checkboxes.

[image: Disable mentions salesforce communities]